# How to solve ODEs with Java?

Tags: java, math, apache-commons, ode

I'm trying to solve an ODE with Java and so far I have tried two different libraries. The one I trust the most is [Apache Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/ode.html) however even for simple problems I don't seem to get the correct solution.

When I solve my system in *Mathematica* I get this:

[image: correct]

whereas if I solve it with the Dormand-Prince 8(5,3) solver in Apache Commons Math I get this:

[image: incorrect]

According to the theory behind this the circle should be closed like in the first picture. How can I get this solution in Java?

Here is the Java code I currently use (I have tested different settings for step size etc.):

program.java:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.*;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.nonstiff.DormandPrince853Integrator;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.sampling.StepHandler;
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.sampling.StepInterpolator;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FirstOrderIntegrator dp853 = new DormandPrince853Integrator(1.0E-8, 10E-5, 1.0E-20, 1.0E-20);
        FirstOrderDifferentialEquations ode = new CometSun();

        double G = 1.48808E-34;
        double sunMass = 1.9891E30;

        double a = 1;
        double e = 0.1;
        double rp = a*(1-e);
        double v0 = sqrt(G*sunMass*(2/rp-1/a));
        double t = 2*PI*sqrt(pow(a,3)/(G*sunMass));

        double[] y = new double[6];

        y[0] = -rp;
        y[1] = 0;
        y[2] = 0;

        y[3] = 0;
        y[4] = v0;
        y[5] = 0;

        StepHandler stepHandler = new StepHandler() {

            ArrayList<String> steps = new ArrayList<String>();

            public void init(double t0, double[] y0, double t) {

            }

            public void handleStep(StepInterpolator interpolator, boolean isLast) {
                double   t = interpolator.getCurrentTime();
                double[] y = interpolator.getInterpolatedState();

                if( t > steps.size() )
                    steps.add(t + " " + y[0] + " " + y[1] + " " + y[2]);

                if(isLast) {
                    try{
                        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("results.txt"), "UTF-8");
                        for(String step: steps) {
                            writer.println(step);
                        }
                        writer.close();
                    } catch(Exception e) {};
                }
            }
        };
        dp853.addStepHandler(stepHandler);

        dp853.integrate(ode, 0.0, y, t, y);

        System.out.println(y[0]);
        System.out.println(y[1]);
    }

}
```

CometSun.java:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.ode.FirstOrderDifferentialEquations;

import static java.lang.Math.*;

public class CometSun implements FirstOrderDifferentialEquations {

    double G = 1.48808E-34;
    double sunMass = 1.9891E30;

    public int getDimension() {
        return 6;
    }

    public void computeDerivatives(double t, double[] y, double[] yp) {
        double coeff = G*sunMass/pow(pow(y[0],2)+pow(y[1],2)+pow(y[2],2),3/2);

        yp[0] = y[3];
        yp[1] = y[4];
        yp[2] = y[5];

        yp[3] = -coeff*y[0];
        yp[4] = -coeff*y[1];
        yp[5] = -coeff*y[2];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can neither predict nor promise or verify that you'll receive *exactly* the same results as Mathematica: There are some very large and some very small numbers involved, and you might hit the limitations of the `double` precision.

But in this case, the main reason for the error is most likely a very simple and very subtle one:

```
double coeff = G*sunMass/pow(pow(y[0],2)+pow(y[1],2)+pow(y[2],2),3/2);
```

The last exponent is 1. You are performing an integer division there, and 3/2 yields 1. You could change this to

```
double coeff = G*sunMass/pow(pow(y[0],2)+pow(y[1],2)+pow(y[2],2),3.0/2.0);
```

and see whether you get closer to the perfect circle.

BTW: Computing x² as pow(x,2) is **very** inefficient. If efficiency may be an issue here (and I assume that it is), you should consider writing this as something like

```
double yy0 = y[0]*y[0];
double yy1 = y[1]*y[1];
double yy2 = y[2]*y[2];
double coeff = G*sunMass/pow(yy0+yy1+yy2,3.0/2.0);
```

Comment: This is why I only use python because confusion about integer division never happens in python... oh, wait.